# How can I add conditions in my sql request?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, bdd

Please I have a question about mysql request.

I have below two tables named:

```
PROFILE
PROFILEXCEPTION
```

In my request, I want to search in a first time if the name of my equipment exists in the table `PROFILE`, if yes I return the result, else I search in the second table `PROFILEXCEPTION`.

How can I do it in a one request.

Comment: you need all rows if multiple exist for same equipment or just need first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to get the data from table `profile`:

```
select last_name 
from profile
where first_name = 'John';
```

And this is the query to get the data from table `profileexception` if it doesn't exist in table `profile`:

```
select last_name 
from profilexception
where first_name = 'John'
and not exists
(
  select *
  from profile
  where first_name = 'John'
);
```

So the second query will only produce output, if the first one doesn't.

Glued together with `UNION ALL`:

```
select last_name 
from profile
where first_name = 'John'
union all
select last_name 
from profilexception
where first_name = 'John'
and not exists
(
  select *
  from profile
  where first_name = 'John'
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's what I was searching for